# (Durrett : Probability : Theory and Examples 5th ed, Excercise 3.4.13 ) Lindeberg Feller Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, central-limit-theorem

The problem is

> Suppose $P(X_j=j)=P(X_j=-j)=1/2j^{\beta}$ and $P(X_j=0)=1-j^{-\beta}$ where $\beta>0$. Show that if $\beta <1 $ then $S_n/n^{(3-\beta)/2}\Rightarrow c \chi$.

Here is one solution using characteristic function( [Let $P(X_j=j)=P(X_j=-j)=1/2j^{\beta}$ and $P(X_j=0)=1-j^{-\beta}$ where $\beta\in(0,1)$, then $S_n/n^{(3-\beta)/2)}\Rightarrow c\chi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030072/let-px-j-j-px-j-j-1-2j-beta-and-px-j-0-1-j-beta-where-beta-i?rq=1) ).

But can we prove this using Lindeberg Feller Theorem?

Letting $X_{n,m} = \frac{X_m}{n^{(3-\beta)/2}}$,
it is easy to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{m=1}E[
X_{n,m}^2]\rightarrow \sigma$.

However I can't prove that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{m=1}E[X_{n,m}^2;|X_{n,m}|>\epsilon]\rightarrow 0$$